# View video on Screen while listen audio in android

Tags: android, audio-streaming, upnp, airplay, mpd

Is it possible to stream all pc audio throug `mpd`, `raop`, `UPnP` or something like? I want to play video on a big screen far from where I'm sitting and be able to hear the audio Streamed trough my phone.